# Ubuntu 20.04 screen green flickering Lenovo IdeaPad S145-15AST

Tags: 64-bit, screen, amdgpu

i did use ubuntu for more than a year on this laptop
last a few days i used HDMI cable, today for a few hours i did use a new cable "longer one"
now suddenly my laptop display went green as you can see https://launchpadlibrarian.net/644322972/20230104_215719.jpg

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2001721

Comment: Are you sure it's not a faulty (*or just bad*) cable?  HDMI is intentionally a poor standard with regards quality so as to make it harder to pirate media (*intended to make it harder to copy DVD or other purchased medial with poor connections showing incorrect/changing color or all black*).  Your description reads like a *faulty* cable.

Comment: Now if i remove the cable or keep it, my laptop stays the same green flickering, But the other screen over HDMI is ok,

Comment: Check the [cable] connections are correctly inserted (*and not partially inserted; both ends*)

Comment: i did check it's ok.

Comment: i removed the HDMI, and the laptop screen still the same green bad looking.

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem, does it happen when you're in the BIOS, ie before Ubuntu boots? Usually there a key combination to switch the outputs (eg Fn+F7, but specific to every different model), try switching the outputs and see if the laptop works then?